# Java - handle file upload and create a new http request efficiently

Tags: java, file-upload, http-post

In my custom application I accept files through a file upload form and get MultipartFile object. Then according to the other parameters in the upload form I make some processing and I prepare another post request including the file and send the request  to another server.

The code I use is as follows :

In the controller part I take the input steram

```
             MultipartFile file = uploadedFile.getFile();
             InputStream inputStream = file.getInputStream();
```

The stream is passed to service method and the new request is prepared as below

```
            CloseableHttpClient closeableHttpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();

            HttpPost uploadFile = new HttpPost(url + port + path);

            MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();

            .... other parameters set here....


            multipartEntityBuilder.addBinaryBody("attachment", IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream), ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, fileName);

            HttpEntity httpEntity = multipartEntityBuilder.build();

            uploadFile.setEntity(httpEntity);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = closeableHttpClient.execute(uploadFile);
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this, is the transformation of

```
     file.getInputStream()
```

to

```
     byte[] // by IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream)
```

really needed?

Any other advice for the method is also appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can call the `multipartEntityBuilder.addBinaryBody` method directly with `inputStream` as below:

```
multipartEntityBuilder.addBinaryBody("attachment", IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream), ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, fileName);
```

So there will be a great increase in memory usage that was caused by IOUtils.toByteArray() method and file will be sent via streaming.